# v-if when router path changes

Tags: vuejs2

may anyone help.

Is it possible to show some DOM element when route pat changes.
Code

```
<div>
   <router-link v-if="$router.history.current['path'] !=='user/config'"
   class="btn btn-fill 
   btn-default" 
   tag="button" 
   to="/user/config">Change Config
    </router-link>
</div>
```

It works, but only when refreshing a page, how to listen to event of `$router.history.current['path]` changed?

Full component code:

```
    <template>
  <card class="card-user">
    <img slot="image" src="https://ununsplash.imgix.net/photo-1431578500526-4d9613015464?fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=300&q=75&w=400" alt="..."/>
       <router-link class="btn btn-fill btn-default" tag="button" to="/user/password-change">Change Passsword</router-link>
      </div>
      <div>
        <router-link class="btn btn-fill btn-default" tag="button" to="/user/password-change">Change Email</router-link>
      </div>
      <div>
        <router-link  v-if="v-if="$router.history.current['path'] !== '/user/config'"" class="btn btn-fill btn-default" tag="button" to="/user/config">Change Config</router-link>
      </div>
    </div>
  </card>
</template>
<script>
  import Card from 'src/components/UIComponents/Cards/Card.vue'
  export default {
    components: {
      Card
    },
    data () {
      return {
      }
    }
  }

</script>
```

But also this component is child  User Thx

Comment: it should work just fine. created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zeLwtxsb/) check it out.

Comment: @Jag add all code and this component is render by User component so i need to send event there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem could be that you are using the same `User` component to render both `/user` and `/user/config` routes. If this is the setup, `vue-router` doesn't reload or re-render the component. To make the view react to changes in the path one option would be that of adding a parameter that changes. In this way, the router would handle the change (see vue-router docs on [Dynamic Route Matching](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/dynamic-matching.html)). If you don't want to change your routes to add this parameter, a trick is to add a changing `:key` to `<router-view>`:

```
<router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
```

this will trigger a component full-lifecycle whenever the path changes (beware that this could impact performance for those components that wouldn't need a re-render).
Then in your `User` component:

```
<template>
  ...
  <router-link  v-if="isNotInConfig()" class="btn btn-fill btn-default" tag="button" to="/user/config">Change Config</router-link>
  ...
</template>

<script>
export default {
  ...
  methods: {
    isNotInConfig() {
      return this.$router.history.current["path"] !== "/user/config";
    }
  },
  ...
};
<script>
```

#### Live demo

I've put together a full working live [demo on codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/9jloq57k7p).

Comment: I want to hide button if i am on some route path?

Comment: I have edited the question may be now will be more understandable

Comment: @marco-pantaleoni How might one conditionally limit the re-render to a route (or dynamic route) so it doesn't apply to all routes and impact performance, as you noted? Your answer here has been very helpful towards solving the issue I've posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62827356/vue-router-trigger-refresh-when-changing-dynamic-route-via-next-previous-post-l Can I somehow limit the full-lifecycle re-render to changes within a specific Vue component/view template?