# Vue router- Trigger refresh when changing dynamic route via next/previous post links in blog

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm relatively new to Vue, and I'm working on a portfolio site that is essentially structured like a blog with single/detail views for each project, i.e. `SingleProject.vue` and are linked using dynamic routes based on the slug name, i.e. `path: "/projects/:project_name_slug"`. In the template, I'm using Axios to request JSON data from a CMS, and passing the data to a `post` variable via a `fetchPosts()` function. I'm then running `this.fetchPosts()` on the `mounted` life cycle hook. On this single project view, I also have links to the **next** and **previous** projects based on the order defined in the CMS. I'm saving JSON data to respective arrays for `nextPost` and `prevPost` and then creating router links using the post slug names as follows:

```
<router-link
    v-if="nextPost"
    :to="{path: '/projects/' + nextPost.project_name_slug}"
>Next Project</router-link>
```

**Now to get to my actual question:** these links for next/previous posts work fine; but when clicked, the view does not fully refresh/transition, and all the text data—title, sidebar info, etc.— changes rapidly, but the images lag a bit while they're downloaded (see diagram below for a visual.) So, for a moment, one will see an image from the previous project alongside text info for the next one, while the new image loads. This is a bit distracting/off-putting, so I'm trying to find a way to essentially reload the view (as if one were clicking to a different [static] route altogether) when clicking on one of these links to change the dynamic route. I found [this helpful SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49882850/v-if-when-router-path-changes), which suggests adding a changing key to `<router-view>` to trigger a full lifecycle whenever the path changes, i.e.

```
<router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
```

This approach works, and indeed forces the whole SingleProject view (images and all) to refresh when changing routes via the next/previous links. However, I'm wondering if there is a better/more efficient way to limit this lifecycle refresh to just the dynamic (project view) routes? I realize, as noted in that thread, this approach could impact performance by forcing the recycle on *all* route changes, not just those related to single project views. Please let me know if this is unclear in any way- and thanks for any insight!

[image: SingleProject.vue layout diagram]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to earn such kind of thing you can do it by putting all needed routes into a variable which is an Object. Then you can define some logics to switch between them and apply to a component and use it globally.

Ah, by the way,  You can use a good tool called Vuepress. It has its own Previous and Next link buttons. **You can say it is for documentation.** **No** you can make ***blogs*** and ***portfolios*** too. There are so many projects created with Vuepress on the internet.
And even you can ***change layouts, styles or create your own theme*** from zero.

Below you can find link to many different projects and websites.
And most of them are ready themes to use in your projects.
https://github.com/topics/vuepress-theme